# How to prove that there a constant $C$ such that $\arcsin \frac{1-x}{1+x}+2\arctan\sqrt{x}=C$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

How to prove that there a constant $C$ such that $\arcsin \frac{1-x}{1+x}+2\arctan\sqrt{x}=C$?

I have no idea using which theorem to prove. Could someone show me how to start the problem?

Comment: If something is a constant, its derivative is zero.

Comment: If you differentiate you will get some constant value fir x implying whole expression has a constant value